# How to reduce the amount of memory used by consecutive Graphics.DrawImage()

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-management, picturebox

I'm working on building an application that displays one of three images in a list `images` on a picture box every 3 seconds, and the way I did this is by loading one of the images directly into the picture box using

`drawing.Image = Image.FromFile(images[1]);`

Then I used the Graphics class to draw the other 2 images.

```
void PictureBox_Paint_alarm(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (rotationCounter > images.Count-1)
                rotationCounter = 0;
            if (rotationCounter != 1)
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(images[rotationCounter]), new RectangleF(0, 0, drawing.Size.Width, drawing.Size.Height));
        }
```

The `rotationCounter` increments by 1 every 3 seconds and the application function as intended. However, I have noticed that the program is consuming more memory as time goes by, until it reaches 5 Gigabytes then it goes back to 400 KB, the images have an average size of 450 KB.

The problem is that I'm going to be deploying this program on a system that only has 2 GB of RAM

Comment: Write a `using` clause for `Image.FromFile`?

Comment: memory is allocated for the application until there is free memory in the system. So  the `GC` will be started earlier on 2GB RAM computer. You can dispose the old `drawing.Image` like [it is documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox?view=netframework-4.8) when new Image is going to be assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `images` array (or something very like it) that is currently storing file names. Instead of doing that, load the images *once* and have an array of *those* instead of file names. That way you're not constantly reloading the images from file.

That also means you don't keep creating very (resource) expensive `Image` objects. Those things implement `IDisposable` and so are meant to be disposed when no longer required. You're instead just letting them sit around until they're Garbage Collected:

> until it reaches 5 Gigabytes then it goes back to 400 KB, the images have an average size of 450 KB.

Which is exactly what you're describing here.

> The problem is that I'm going to be deploying this program on a system that only has 2 GB of RAM

And that wouldn't be a problem because a) programs don't allocate physical memory and b) the Garbage Collector would kick in earlier when memory pressure sets in.

Comment: I loaded all three images into a list of images and then used it to update the picture box, now the program is taking long to consume 1 GB of RAM, I will force a garbage collection to occur every 45 seconds to avoid having the program exceeds 1 GB

Comment: @O. Bokhari If your memory usage still grows, then you have other memory leaks. For example, because you embedded the Images as Resources and you're using `Properties.Resources.[Image]` as the source of the Image to draw, thus generating a new Image each time. Also, Pen, Brush and Font (and other GDI+ objects) need to be disposed of, usually declaring them with a `using` statement. If you draw images properly and dispose of disposable objects, the memory usage doesn't grow. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GC.Collect(); to use Garbage Collector.

Also if you have declared objects, you can use DeleteObject() to delete it after use.

This link might be useful:
[Deleting & Releasing GDI objects](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/204260/How-to-delete-or-release-the-GDI-objects-in-VC)